# What is the correct inversion symmetry in a two-band model

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, parity, time-reversal-symmetry

Consider a simple two-band tight-binding model
$$H(k)=\sin{k_x}\,\sigma_x+\sin{k_y}\,\sigma_y + \left(\sum_{i=x,y,z}\cos{k_i}-2\right)\sigma_z.$$
Let's assume $H$ is for real spins. It breaks the time-reversal symmetry $T=i\sigma_yK$ with complex conjugation $K$.
Then for real spins, I presume the inversion operation $I$ should be just $k\rightarrow-k$ and it does not hold in $H$.
However, there is another symmetry $I'=\sigma_z$ satisfied by $H$ as $I'H(-k){I'}^{-1}=H(k)$. What is this symmetry then? (It is not particle-hole, which will otherwise include $K$.)

If $H$ is for pseudospins, $T$ becomes $T=K$ and is still broken. And now it looks not weird to have $I$ different from simple $k\rightarrow-k$ and hence $I'$ seems OK to be the inversion here?

So questions:

1. If $H$ is for real spins, is there inversion symmetry at all and what is $I'$?
2. For a given form of $H(k)$, whether a symmetry is there can depend on how we interpret the model (like real or pseudospin)?

Answer (score -1):

There is no inversion complementing $\vec x\to -\vec x$, because the linear transformations transpose and complex conjugate only reverse the same imaginary $\sigma_y$ in the defining $sl(2,C)$ representation. So an equation of time evolution

$$\partial_t u - i A_0 u  =  (\vec \sigma \cdot (\vec \nabla - i \vec A )) \ u $$

does not contain any mirror operators. One needs the $Cl(4,R)$ Clifford algebra, that yields the  missing algebra element for the time direction.

Geometrically,  the space inversion operator in the 2-sphere $\theta \to \pi -\theta,\  \phi \to \phi\pm\pi $
maps the spinor Hilbert space  to a different one because there are square roots of $\sin, cos$ present.